# Syntax Error in programmatically generated query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Im facing mysqli_fetch_array() error and its telling the following

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

im preparing a pagination process where my code goes like this.

```
$_SESSION['sub']=$sub; // this holds the name of database which is working fine
$ques_per_page=1; // LIMIT 
$page_result = ($page-1)*$ques_per_page; //determines the SQL LIMIT starting number for the result on displaying page
$sql="SELECT question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4 FROM " .$sub. "LIMIT". $page_result .','. $ques_per_page ; // it is where error is
```

Don't know what is going wrong

Comment: Print out the final `$sql` string, and take a look at this. Also please make question titles here more descriptive (technical details, not personal woes), and put a full code excerpt into a code block.

Comment: You don't have any spaces around the word `LIMIT`. You query will look something like `...FROM tableNameLIMIT1,...`

Comment: you miss a space before and after LIMIT. Change "LIMIT" to " LIMIT "

Comment: Whenever you get issues with query, try printing the query and take a look at it or try  running it in db

Comment: @Saurabh: It could be dangerous to use data extracted right from the Session, and to inject it into an SQL command.

Comment: `$sql="SELECT question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4 FROM " .$sub. " LIMIT ". $page_result .", ". $ques_per_page;`

Comment: actually i need to extract data from different database and tables on the same page according to the selected category. and category name is the name of database and then $sub is table name... if u could suggest any better way it will be great im new to it thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're missing a space before and after the `LIMIT` keyword.

But, it would help if you could paste the complete, expanded string, after all the PHP variables replacements.

Side note: it is generally considered bad practice to chain a string using the `.` concatenation operator instead of simply using variable interpolation, as in:

`$sql = "SELECT question, ans1, ans2 from ${sub} LIMIT ${page_result}, ${ques_per_page}";`

from your example.

Comment: *it is generally considered bad practice to chain a string using the . concatenation operator* - would you like to quote some source for this?!

Comment: @NigelRen: check `@bjacquemont` on Twitter, in particular his conference about Opcodes and the Zend Optimiser.

Comment: Your string could be: `"SELECT question, ans1, ans2 FROM \`$sub\` LIMIT $page_result, $ques_per_page"`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: What are the back-ticks for, in your string?

Comment: The backticks would safeguard against reserved words or non-standard table names when substituted in for `$sub`.

Comment: @NigelRen: Ah, yes, correct for MySql. Btw in general one should avoid using data from session, as table names or other pieces injected into an SQL command.

Comment: @gabriel why do you need to use braces in your string? Why you should avoid using data from sessions? You should indeed mention that Prepared Statements are the right way to pass variables to a query

Comment: @LelioFaieta: your questions could be an entire thread on their own, not necessarily related to the OP's problem. But in essence: it is not impossible to forge session data and to exploit SQL injection when placing in an SQL string some variables without pre-validation or escaping -- yes you are right, one should consider prepared statements, although prepared statement won't allow you to parameterize table names: only data values. As for the `${var}` syntax: it is a good reflex I took on, so as to comprehend indexed vars as well (as in `${arr[$i]}`).

Answer (score 0):

it worked 
i wrote the query like this 
`$sql="SELECT * FROM $sub LIMIT $page_result, $ques_per_page" ;`instead of `$sql="SELECT question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4 FROM " .$sub. "LIMIT". $page_result .','. $ques_per_page ;`
thank you all for responses.....